# Авто-таргет и стрельба

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть код:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Target : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform player;
    public float range = 15;
    public int enemyLayer = 8;

    public Texture2D aim;
    public float aimSize = 50;

    private GameObject currentTarget;
    private Collider[] colliders = new Collider[0];

    void OnGUI() {
        if (currentTarget) {
            Vector2 tmp = new Vector2(Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(currentTarget.transform.position).x,
                                      Screen.height - Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(currentTarget.transform.position).y);
            Vector2 offset = new Vector2(-aimSize / 2, -aimSize / 2);
            GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(tmp.x + offset.x, tmp.y + offset.y, aimSize, aimSize), aim);
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        GetTarget();
        if (colliders.Length == 0) {
            currentTarget = null;
        } else {
            float curDist = Vector3.Distance(player.position, currentTarget.transform.position);
            if (curDist > range) {
                currentTarget = null;
            }
        }
    }

    void SetTarget() {
        if (colliders.Length > 0) {
            Collider currentCollider = null;
            float dist = Mathf.Infinity;
            foreach (Collider collider in colliders) {
                float currentDist = Vector3.Distance(player.position, collider.transform.position);
                if ((currentTarget && currentDist < dist && currentTarget != collider.gameObject) || currentDist < dist) {
                    currentCollider = collider;
                    dist = currentDist;
                }
            }
            currentTarget = currentCollider.gameObject;
        }
    }

    void GetTarget() {
        colliders = new Collider[0];
        colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(player.position, range, 1 << enemyLayer);
        if (currentTarget) {
            return;
        }
        SetTarget();
    }
}
```

Код работает.
Но мне нужно сделать, чтобы он работал более правильно по отношению к моей задаче.
Есть 2 объекта, один на земле, второй в воздухе.
Мне нужно сделать так, что-бы если `N` дистанция до объекта совпадает то таргет взят, но если он уже пролетает над ним, то таргет теряется, то есть угол стрельбы должен быть примерно такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И еще такой момент, когда объект который в воздухе разворачивается влево или вправо, чтобы таргет терялся, как мне сделать, чтобы он только лицом к земному объекту брал в таргет? (Лицом пусть даже считается объект пушка)
То-есть, если отклонение больше чем на `N` градусов, чтобы терялся таргет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста с расчетом, никак не могу разобраться...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все теперь работает правильно.

```
Vector3 CurrentTargetPos = currentTarget.transform.position;
CurrentTargetPos.y = transform.position.y;
Vector3 TargetDist = CurrentTargetPos - transform.position;
float angle = Vector3.Angle(TargetDist, transform.forward);
if (angle > maxAngle) {
    currentTarget = null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Считаем угол цели относительно игрока

```
float Ang = Mathf.Atan2(target.y-player.y, target.x-player.x)/Mathf.PI*180f;
```

Находим разницу между углом поворота игрока и найденый

```
float DeltaAng = Mathf.DeltaAngle(playerAng, Ang);
```

Устанавливаем диапазон в `N` градусов

```
if (Mathf.Abs(DeltaAng ) < nAng) { /*tracking*/ }
else { /*lost taget*/ }
```

Comment: Можете показать куда это написать? Или было бы хорошо, чтобы мой код поправили. Уже измучился... Я пробовал написать в `FixedUpdate` - в конец метода следующее: `Vector3 lookPos = currentTarget.transform.position - player.position;

            if(Vector3.Angle(lookPos, transform.forward) > 30f) {
                currentTarget = null;
            }` - работает не совсем верно. Ваш код мне также написать в `FixedUpdate`? И что есть `nAng`, откуда взялся? Было бы прекрасно. если бы вы, помогли записать это рабочим кодом.